# Is it ok to ignore the skin on top of my stock?

Tags: stock

When I make a stock, I generally skim the foam for the first few hours, and usually it stops showing up.  But as I've increased my cooking time, I've started to see a clear skin forming on top of the stock. Usually around 14-24 hours in. Unlike the foam it's pretty difficult to skim out as it wants to stick to the meat, vegetables and herbs floating at the surface.

I tasted some of it and it didn't have a terrible flavor. Mostly just tasted like the fat floating on the stock.  What is this stuff, and is it ok to ignore?

Answer (score 1):

It could be gelatin from the broken down bones and connective tissue.

Comment: Agreed. I think it is a layer of gelatine/protein from the surface where the water has evaporated. I think you should leave it in as it is part of what makes your stock so good.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's the fat from what ever meat or poultry your using. You can leave it, it will usually solidify when you chill your stock and you can then just lift it off. Or leave it for added flavor.

Comment: There is a large amout of fat, however this skin is floating on top of the fat.  It is clear, and sticky/chewy.  Maybe it is broken down protein?